# patched powerline fonts on gnome-terminal not working (archlinux + GNOME)

Tags: vim, archlinux, gnome-terminal, powerline, vim-airline

I am facing a problem on my newly installed arch linux machine with GNOME - vim is unable to render powerline glyphs on the gnome-terminal. I have installed the patched fonts and changed the gnome-terminal preferences to use the powerline font. Also, I have installed powerline and powerline-fonts using pacman. I use vim-airline plugin with the setting "let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1". I tried different powerline fonts and none of them resolved the problem. pango-list command displays me all the powerline fonts too. I have tried a lot of different variations to fix this problem but, I haven't been able to get anything to work. Any help would be highly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal isn't showing few characters in the above screenshot
Either fonts with those characters aren't installed or Encoding of terminal isn't set to UTF-8
You've installed glyphs, in that case, only option left is adding the following line in .vimrc
`set encoding=utf-8`

You also need to confirm that terminal is configured to display UTF-8 encoding
Check the compatibility tab in gnome-terminal preferences
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It was a trivial issue with fonts. I had to install a relevant Nerd Font.